# Subnetting design for a new building?

Tags: networking, subnet

A building with 4 floors, each floor is divided as follows; 15 users for accounting, 15 users for finance and 15 users for marketing (i.e 45 user in each floor).

Data center is located on the ground floor, with 45 servers to be divided into 15 for all the accounting users in the four floors, another 15 for the finance and the last 15 for the marketing. (i.e each 15 server for each one of the above categories are separated from the other 15 and so on)

What is the proper subnetting design for such scenario? Knowing that we are allowed to use anything we want!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! We're more than happy to help you answer real questions, but answering homework questions is rather off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Why you think you Need subnetting?

This is a small Scenario - not even a /24 on machines. I would put all that one subnets MAYBE based on security (Accounting etc.), but not based on organization.

One subnet for Server room, one for Computers, a router in between (which any decent Switch does These days - simple IP Routing at wire Speed, and you need a decent router in the middle of this).

If you Need to Isolate machines put them on separate Networks via VLAN's. Obviously you establish edge security on the ports, but that is another trivial exercise on homework Level.